# Measure health of HTTP, HTTPS, SOCKS proxies

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, ip, icmp

I have proxy list, like [this](https://free-proxy-list.net/). It contains all kind of proxies: HTTP, HTTPS, SOCKS etc. I want to calculate heartbeat (health) of each proxy each `X` minutes.

I've found nice example how people ping IP addresses through Java sockets:

```
Socket s = new Socket(hostname, port);
s.getOutputStream().write((byte) '\n');
int ch = s.getInputStream().read();
s.close();
if (ch == '\n') // its all good.
```

### Question

*Which protocol (protocols) I need to use to ping HTTP, HTTPS, SOCKS servers?*

Comment: @JimGarrison could u pls explain me if TPC ping enough in my case? I'm not sure I need ICMP

Comment: Have you considered using Proxicity.io for this? They have an API that serves public proxies that have been checked and verified. They remove the old, broken proxies and add new ones constantly. Check it out - https://www.proxicity.io

Answer (score 2):

That code does not use ICMP, it opens a TCP connection to a port.

Opening a TCP connection (or, actually, using ICMP) only verifies that the host network stack is capable of responding, it does not verify the health of the proxy itself.  To do that you'd have to actually make a connection using the proxy protocol and verify proxying to an outside resource.

Comment: could I use some low level protocol to use the same code for all kinds of proxies?

Comment: HTTP, SOCKS, etc are different proxy protocols, you would have to code for each one separately. You would have to implement a higher level interface (connect to target server W:X via proxy Y:Z) with a different wrapper for each protocol, and then you can choose which one to use on a connection-by-connection basis.